# Replace particular characters in the string at the same moment

Tags: javascript, string, replace

```
var str = 'Hello World'
var replacements = {0: '4', 6: '77'};
magicalReplace(str, replacements);
// result: 4ello 77orld
```

Can you help me write that function which would help solve the problem?
The most important thing is to replace it at the same moment, because replacement may be longer than single character.

Comment: No need for "at the same moment" - sort the edits by descending order of position (`6` then `0` in your example), then make the edits in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This snippet should do the job, also accounting for unsorted keys:

```
String.prototype.magicalReplace = function(replacements) {
    var chars = this.split("");
    for(var key in replacements) {
        if(replacements.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            chars[key] = replacements[key];
        }
    }

    return chars.join("");
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HdCFj/